# Problem while using @OneToOne unidirectionnal mapping when updating parent entity : child 'isn't persisted

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple Parent / Child use case that give me some hard time to make it run properly.
Problem is that save operation work as intended but update seems not.

Parent class:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

 private Long id;


 private Fils fils;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 public Long getId() {
     return id;
 }


 public void setId( Long id ) {
     this.id = id;
 }

 @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
 @JoinColumn(name="fils_fk")
 public Fils getFils() {
     return fils;
 }


 public void setFils( Fils fils ) {
     this.fils = fils;
 }    
}
```

Child class:

```
@Entity
public class Fils {

 private Long id;    

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 public Long getId() {
     return id;
 }

 public void setId( Long id ) {
     this.id = id;
 }

}
```

Test class:

```
@Test
public void testSave(){
    Parent p = new Parent();
    p.setFils( new Fils() );
    dao.save( p );
    Assert.assertNotNull( p.getFils().getId() );
    dao.delete( p );
}

@Test
public void testUpdate(){
    Parent p = new Parent();
    dao.save( p );
    Fils f = new Fils();
    p.setFils( f );
    dao.update( p );
    Assert.assertNotNull( p.getFils().getId() );
}
```

save persist Fils object first then Pere object and all is good but update persist only Pere Object.

I used in my ParentDao this code to perform update:

```
public Parent update(Parent p){
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update( p );
    return (Parent)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load( Parent.class, p.getId() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Problem solved.

Replacing in ParentDao the code snippet to perform update with:

```
public Parent update(Parent p){
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist( p );
    return (Parent)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load( Parent.class, p.getId() );
}
```

And tadam update work cascading child entity persistence.

I'd never read that your can't use update and get cascading on this operation.